# Z3 Failing Even After Setting interactive-mode to True

Tags: java, z3, smt

I'm using the Z3 Java API to solve a smt file using the `parseSMT2File()` method. However, even if I set `params.add("interactive-mode", true)` and then `solver.setParameters(params)`, Z3 throws the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.microsoft.z3.Z3Exception: (error "line 276 column 23: model is not available")
(error "line 277 column 26: model is not available")
(error "line 279 column 15: command is only available in interactive mode, use command (set-option :interactive-mode true)")
(error "line 280 column 16: model is not available")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`parseSMT2File()` only parses the assertions from the file, and returns them as one expression. It doesn't run many commands, including `check-sat`, i.e. you have to call `check()` on the solver that you added the assertion to as well.

Comment: Does it parse declarations?

Comment: Yes, but there is no symbol table in which to look up declarations, those would have to be obtained from the parsed expression.